# Margin Calculation based on multiple parameters VBA Macro

Tags: excel, vba

I need help in figuring out the code on this problem.
I need the gross margin to calculate based on multiple parameters in 3 different columns.
This code isn't working. I'm getting an error at this point:

`If ws.Cells(i, "L").Value > 0 Then`

Code here:

```
Sub MARGIN_TWO()

    Dim i As Long, ws As Worksheet
    Set ws = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Summary")
    
    Dim lastRow As Integer 'object creation
    lastRow = Range("I" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    
    For Each cell In Range("M7:M" & lastRow)
        If ws.Cells(i, "L").Value > 0 Then
            ws.Cells(i, "L").Value
        
        ElseIf ws.Cells(i, "R").Value > 0 Then  

        Select Case ws.Cells(i, "F").Value = "Removed"
        
        Case ws.Cells(i, "X").Value = "L"
            Active.Formula = "formula"

        Case ws.Cells(i, "X").Value = "M"
            Active.Formula = "formula"

        Case ws.Cells(i, "X").Value = "R"
            Active.Formula = "formula"
        
        Case ws.Cells(i, "X").Value = "B"
            Active.Formula = "N/A"
        
        Case ws.Cells(i, "R").Value = 0 Or ws.Cells(i, "R").Value = "#N/A"
            Active.Formula = "N/A"
            
        End Select
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

---

This is 1 part of the code because I think I will have to go through this process a few times in order to encompass all the parameters. If I can get this part of the code, I know I can replicate the rest.
Error message: Application-Defined or Object-defined error
[image]

---

Updated Code:
Dim i As Integer, ws As Worksheet
Set ws = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Summary")

```
Dim lastRow As Long 'object creation
lastRow = Range("I" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
 i = i + 1 'Start i off as 1
For Each cell In Range("M7:M" & lastRow)
    
    If ws.Cells(i, "L").Value > 0 Then
        ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=RC[-1]"
        i = i + 1
        
    ElseIf ws.Cells(i, "R").Value > 0 Then  'removed-rebated by PGC (i, "R").Value > 0

    Select Case ws.Cells(i, "F").Value = "Removed"
    
    Case ws.Cells(i, "X").Value = "L"
        ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "formula"
        i = i + 1
    Case ws.Cells(i, "X").Value = "M"
        ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "formula"
        i = i + 1
    Case ws.Cells(i, "X").Value = "R"
        ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "formula"
         i = i + 1
    Case ws.Cells(i, "X").Value = "B"
        ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "N/A"
        i = i + 1
    Case ws.Cells(i, "R").Value = 0 Or ws.Cells(i, "R").Value = "#N/A"
        ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "N/A"
        i = i + 1
    End Select
    End If
Next
```

Comment: You never gave `i` a value so it is currently a 0, there is no row 0.

Answer (score 0):

It's best to set lastRow as long, and i as integer, then give i the value of 1 before starting the For loop, and right before Next write i = i + 1

Also, right after the If line, there is the following line ws.Cells(i, "L").Value that is not equal to anything. It should be something like  ws.Cells(i, "L").Value = "OK" or dunno, it must do something.

Comment: Don't use integers, you almost certainly don't need the reduced memory for a VBA script, it has a worse performance than a long since it is converted in the background, and there are far more rows in excel than there are values in an integer so you're likely to get overflows.

Comment: Since the `For Each` isn't being used, might as well make it a `For` and then you don't need to manually increment the variable the loop is for.

Comment: I'll make the object changes as you suggest.  I need the result to be whatever the value is in the cell in column L for that row.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I think I'm close but it is not going to the next cell.